# Real time programming in C++

Tags: c++, real-time, robotics

I have two C++ classes, `objecManip` and `updater`.  The `updater` class has a timer to check the status of the robot arm of my application.

If it moving then do nothing, else getNextAction() from the actions queue.

The actions queue is populated with class `objectManip`.  I have a global variable: `current_status` of the robot arm that I need in `objectManip`.

The problem is that when filling in actions queue `current_status` is taken constantly not dynamically.

Comment: Why did post the code seem a bad idea?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: current_status value is taken as its content when filling in actions queue and i need it dynamical so that it takes the new value when calling the action in updater.

Comment: @Eric Leschinski: very bad edition, You had not to go in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is very unclear, so this is really a stab in the dark, but you need to use atomic data types. With C++11, you have `std::atomic` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/atomic/). For an earlier version of C++, I think you need to use some library or compiler specific data type, which offers atomic data types.

If you make some assumptions about how multithreading works for your CPU and operating system, you *may* get away with just declaring shared variables `volatile` and reading value to temp variable when you use it. `volatile` is really meant for cases like reading hardware-mapped values, where value must be read from the memory every time, so many optimizations are not possible. It does not guarantee atomic updates in itself, because a thread modifying a value may be interrupted in the middle of update, and then another read may read invalid, partially updated value. For booleans this should be fairly safe. For integers which do not cross memory word boundary and which word size or less, this may be safe on many CPUs, which will not interrupt a thread in the middle of writing single memory word. Otherwise, it is data corruption waiting to happen. Some (today uncommon) CPUs also do not synchronize caches between multiple CPU cores, and in that case `volatile` will not help, different threads may see different cached value. So conclusion: use `volatile` as last resort hack!